# Javascript: indexing and searching

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a large array of users which are comprised of 3 different user types `("Admin", "Moderator", "User")`. Each user will have the following properties: `("name", "companyId", "type")`.

The first method will take 1 parameter: an array of users and must return a grouped list according to the user property "type".

The second method will take 4 parameters: a grouped list (result from the first method), an array of user types to include in the search, a string representing the user property to filter by and a string representing the value of the user property. This method must return an array of users as per the search parameters.

My method constructions are returning weird results. Could someone help?

```js
let userTypes = ["Admin", "Moderator", "User"] 

function orchestrateUsers(users) {
    let result = [];

    users.forEach(user => {

        result.push({
            "name": user.name,
            "type": user.type
          });
    });
    return result;
}

function searchUsers(orchestratedUsers, userTypes, property, value) {

}



const users= [{
    "name": "Joe",
    "companyId": "A2100",
    "type": "Admin"
  },
  {
    "name": "Jane",
    "companyId": "A2100",
    "type": "Moderator"
  },
  {
    "name": "Smith",
    "companyId": "A2100",
    "type": "User"
  },
  {
    "name": "Smith",
    "companyId": "A2100",
    "type": "User"
  },
  {
    "name": "Rocket",
    "companyId": "A3100",
    "type": "Admin"
  },
  {
    "name": "Rick",
    "companyId": "A3100",
    "type": "User"
  },
  {
    "name": "Tim",
    "companyId": "A4100",
    "type": "Admin"
  }
]

console.log(orchestrateUsers(users));
```

Comment: "My method constructions are returning weird results. Could someone help?" - could you show us what you've tried already?

Comment: Please share the code which you have tried.

Comment: Edited. For `function orchestrateUsers(users)` I need them to be returned by type. How do I do that? Before I head onto the second function...

Comment: Please ask one question at a time. I have answered the first one :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering the first question

```js
const users = [{ "name": "Joe", "companyId": "A2100", "type": "Admin" }, { "name": "Jane", "companyId": "A2100", "type": "Moderator" }, { "name": "Smith", "companyId": "A2100", "type": "User" }, { "name": "Smith", "companyId": "A2100", "type": "User" }, { "name": "Rocket", "companyId": "A3100", "type": "Admin" }, { "name": "Rick", "companyId": "A3100", "type": "User" }, { "name": "Tim", "companyId": "A4100", "type": "Admin" } ]

function orchestrateUsers(users) {
  let result = {};

  users.forEach(user => {
    if (result[user.type]) result[user.type].push(user.name);
    else result[user.type] = [user.name];
  });
  return result;
}
console.log(orchestrateUsers(users));
```

Comment: How is it possible to program the second function if for example I want to use search by `companyId`? How do I use `ochestratedUsers` for that?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want something like [lodash](https://lodash.com/). Here's an example using [`_.groupBy`](https://lodash.com/docs#groupBy) to group users by type & [`_.filter`](https://lodash.com/docs#filter) to filter for admins:

```js
const users = [
    {"name": "Joe",   "companyId": "A2100", "type": "Admin"},
    {"name": "Jane",  "companyId": "A2100", "type": "Moderator"},
    {"name": "Smith", "companyId": "A2100", "type": "User"},
    {"name": "Rick",  "companyId": "A3100", "type": "User" }
];

var usersByType = _.groupBy(users, function (user) {
    return user.type;
});
console.log(usersByType);

var admins = _.filter(users, function(user) {
    return user.type === "Admin";
});
console.log(admins);

console.log(Object.keys(usersByType));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.js"></script>
```

Run the code snippet to see the console output.

> **Why Lodash?**
>
> Lodash makes JavaScript easier by taking the hassle out of working
>   with arrays, numbers, objects, strings, etc. Lodash’s modular methods
>   are great for:
>
> - Iterating arrays, objects, & strings
> - Manipulating & testing values
> - Creating composite functions